# how to make my side menu responsive to 990px?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made this side menu, which has the icons fixed on the screen on the side, when clicking on the bars opens the full menu. I just can't think of a way to make it responsive, I'd like to make only the menu bars appear in the header when it's 990px, but I can't think of a way to show the icons and the full menu when I click, how can I do that that?

[image: Menu open]

```js
const openBtn = $('.open-btn');
const closeBtn = $('.close-btn');
const offcanvasMenu = $('.offcanvas-menu')

openBtn.on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (offcanvasMenu.hasClass('active')) {
        offcanvasMenu.removeClass('active');
    } else {
        offcanvasMenu.addClass('active');
    }
});

const mouseoverEvent = new Event('mouseenter');

$(".offcanvas-menu a, .icons a").hover(function (obj) {
    const classname = obj.target.classList[0];
    $("."+classname).each((function (i,obj) {
      obj.classList.add("hover")
    }))
}, 
function (obj) {
  const classname = obj.target.classList[0];
    $("."+classname).each((function (i,obj) {
      obj.classList.remove("hover")
    }))
});
```

```css
.header-area {
    background: #111;
    display: flex;
    height: 40px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}

.logo a {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 50px;
}


.icons {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: #111;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9;
}

.icons a{
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.offcanvas-menu a{
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: start;
}

.offcanvas-menu a{
    padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

.offcanvas-menu {
    padding-top: 56px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #111;
    width: auto;
    height: 100vh;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: all .4s ease;
    z-index: 0;
}

.offcanvas-menu.active {
    transform: translateX(60px);
}

.close-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}

a.hover{
    color: #000 !important;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Off Canvas Menu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css">

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Header Area Start -->
    <header class="header-area">

        <nav class="icons d-flex flex-column align-items-center gap-3 text-light">
            <a class="open-btn" href="#">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="home">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="plants">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-solar-panel"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="calendar">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-calendar-days"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="form">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-table-list"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="reports">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-file-invoice-dollar"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="credit">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-dollar-to-slot"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="plantUcs">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-building-user"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="invoice">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-barcode"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="ucs">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-city"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="client">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-users"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="analysis">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass-chart"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="signature">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-file-signature"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="monitoring">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-file-invoice"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="contact">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-headset"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="config">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-gear"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="user">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>
            </a>
        </nav>

        <nav class="offcanvas-menu main-menu d-flex flex-column align-items-center gap-3 text-light">
            <a href="#" class="home">Home</a>
            <a href="#" class="plants">Usinas</a>
            <a href="#" class="calendar">Calendário</a>
            <a href="#" class="form">Formulários</a>
            <a href="#" class="reports">Relatórios</a>
            <a href="#" class="credit">Sistema de crédito</a>
            <a href="#" class="plantUcs">UCS da usina</a>
            <a href="#" class="invoice">Faturas</a>
            <a href="#" class="ucs">UCS</a>
            <a href="#" class="client">Clientes</a>
            <a href="#" class="analysis">Análises</a>
            <a href="#" class="signature">Gerenciamento de assinatura</a>
            <a href="#" class="monitoring">Portais de monitoramento</a>
            <a href="#" class="contact">Contato</a>
            <a href="#" class="config">Configurações</a>
            <a href="#" class="user">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right fa-2xs me-3"></i>
                    Sair
            </a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <!-- Header Area End -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: your css in @media screen and (max-width: 990px) {  display:block   }  this bracket.  and outside of this bracket menu class hide

Comment: Why are you writing your own version of [offcanvas](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/offcanvas/)? You can easily show the labels only for larger screens with [display classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/display/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expecting that this class opens the menu.

```
.offcanvas-menu.active {
    transform: translateX(60px);
}
```

Can add a media prop to your css like so

```
@media (max-width:990px) {
    .offcanvas-menu {
        transform: translateX(60px) !important;
    }
}
```

which will open the menu when window is larger than 990px.
Try omitting the `!important` keyword if it works without it.

Having multiple same values in css can be annoying at times. Can use `:root` directive to help with that.

As an exmaple

```
:root {
    --menu-translate-x: 60px;
}

.offcanvas-menu.active {
    transform: translateX(var(--menu-translate-x));
}
```